# sql how to select the lack of a condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table structure and data for keeping track of horse race results:

```
T_RACE_HISTORY
==============
HORSE_ID   RACE_DT      PLACE
--------   ----------   -----
       1   2014-05-03       1
       1   2014-07-22       1
       1   2016-06-10       3
       2   2016-06-10       2
       3   2016-06-10       1
```

I want a query that returns each unique horse id and either the date of the latest race won by that horse, or null if the horse has never won.

In other words, I want a query with this output:

```
HORSE_ID    RACE_DT
--------    ----------
       1    2014-07-22
       2    (null)
       3    2016-06-10
```

I can get the winning horses with a query like this:

```
SELECT     HORSE_ID,
           MAX(RACE_DT)
FROM       T_RACE_HISTORY
WHERE      PLACE = 1
GROUP BY   HORSE_ID
```

But I have no idea how to look for the *lack* of any won races.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation`:

```
select horse_id,
       max(case when place = 1 then race_dt end)
from t_race_history
group by horse_id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de2ccb/1)

Comment: Wonderful!  Thanks so much.